# Datastax Opscenter 6.0 not sending SNMP trap

Tags: cassandra, snmp, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, snmp-trap

I am using datastax opscenter 6.0 for DSE Cassandra Monitoring. Configuration is done to send SNMP trap but Trap receiver ( HP Openview in this case ) is not receiving this alert. 
I don't see any SNMP realted errors in opscenter logfile. How do I trace the exact error?

Here is my snmp.conf file:

```
 [snmp]
 # set to 1 to enable SNMP trap sending
 enabled=1

 # Levels can be a comma-delimited list of any of the following:
 # DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR,CRITICAL,ALERT
 # If the left is empty, OpsCenter will listen for all levels.
 levels=ALERT

 # Comma-delimited list of cluster names for which
 # this alert config will be eligible to run.
 # If left empty, this alert will be called for events on all clusters.
 clusters=

 # SNMP engine ID, specified by rfc3411 and rfc5343.
 # See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3411#section-5
 # SnmpEngineID definition for more information.
 #
 # 32 octet (max length) unique hex engine ID. Must not be all zeroes or all
 # 255's. The first four octets specify the enterprise ID, left filled
 # with zeroes and starting with an 8. The fifth octet specifies a format scheme
 # that specifies the nature of the remaining octets. The remaining octets
 # are given in accordance with the specified format.
 #
 # Format Schemes:
 # 1 -- IPv4 Address scheme
 # 2 -- IPv6 Address scheme
 # 3 -- MAC Address scheme
 # 4 -- Text Address scheme
 # 5 -- Octets scheme
 #
 # Default scheme is octets scheme; if nothing else, you should change
 # 01020304 to a unique octet string.
 #engine_id=80:00:00:00:05:01:02:03:04

 # IPv4 address of the SNMP target.
 target_ip=*.*.*.*         ( commented due to security urpose )

 # Port to direct traps to on the SNMP target.
 target_port=162

 # Set to 1 to use SNMPv3 and the user/privacy key/auth key model. Set to 0 to
 # use SNMPv1/community model.
 use_snmpv3=0

 # SNMPv1/2 community name (for community security model)
 community_name=public

 # SNMPv3 username
 #user=opscusername

 # SNMPv3 authentication protocol
 # Options:
 #   MD5 -- MD5-based authentication protocol
 #   SHA -- SHA-based authentication protocol
 #   NoAuth -- no authentication to use
 #auth_protocol=SHA

 # SNMPv3 authentication key
 #auth_key=authkey1

 # SNMPv3 privacy protocol
 # Options:
 #   DES -- DES-based encryption protocol
 #   AES -- AES128-based encryption protocol (RFC3826)
 #   3DES -- triple DES-based encryption protocol (Extended Security Options)
 #   AES192 -- AES192-based encryption protocol (Extended Security Options)
 #   AES256 -- AES256-based encryption protocol (Extended Security Options)
 #   NoPriv-- no encryption to use
 #privacy_protocol=AES

 # SNMPv3 privacy key
 #privacy_key=privkey1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `levels=ALERT` to `levels=` and make sure its not just that your filtering the events your looking for first (can turn it back once have it working like you want, just easier to see more things).

Can use wireshark or tcpdump to check if the trap is being sent with something like:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -T snmp  "(port 161 or 162)"
```

(note: eth1 may need to be replaced with your interface name). SNMP clients can be a little bit of a pita in being setup correctly as well, so good to check if they are being sent and not handled vs not sent.

Comment: Following trace dump got generated 07:57:05.158852 IP ukxxxxx.uk.xxxx-intl.com.58993 > snvxxxx.uk.xxx-intl.com.snmptrap:  V2Trap(433)  S:1.1.4.1.0=E:46272.1.0.3 system.sysDescr.0="System Description" E:46272.1.0.2.1.2=2 :46272.1.0.2.1.3="WARN" :46272.1.0.2.1.4="Node  being down: xx.xx.xx.xx" E:46272.1.0.2.1.5=13 :46272.1.0.2.1.6="FICCBTD1"  :46272.1.0.2.1.7="OpsCenter" :46272.1.0.2.1.10="1472194625155000"  :46272.1.0.2.1.11="August 26, 2016 06:57:05 GMT" E:46272.1.0.2.1.8="10.60.16.88" E:46272.1.0.2.1.9="None" E:46272.1.0.2.1.12="None" E:46272.1.0.2.1.13="None"

Comment: It looks from above trace dumps snmp traps are going to HP Openview trap receiver but HP Openivew is not able to get them. Enhanced tracing has been enabled but no trap received from Opscenter servers.